# flutter formkey for validation

Tags: flutter, dart

im trying to make a calculator app and I'm trying to set some validation messages for the text fields like "please enetr numbers only" I used formkey to do that but the validation is not working I'm new to dart I couldn't figure what is the issue

this is my code :

```
    final formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
        child: Form(
          key: formkey,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(height: 45),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  const Text(
                    "Basic Calculator",
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 30),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 60),
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  const Text(
                    "First Number",
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Flexible(
                    child: new TextFormField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      controller: num1controller,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "Enter a number",
                        border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: new BorderSide(color: Colors.teal)),
                      ),
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value!.isEmpty ||
                            !RegExp(r'^[,]*[.][0-9]+$').hasMatch(value!)) {
                          return "please enter  numbers only";
                        } else {
                          return null;
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The given code looks fine to me, however, you are missing one thing. You need to call the `validate()` method on the `currentState` of the form.
Like this `formKey.currentState.validate()`. This is needed to be called in order to validate the form.

Alternatively, you can also use `autovalidateMode` property of the form field (Not tested though). Like: `autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction`. This way you won't need to call the `validate` method on the form state.